# Show that if $c\mid a-b$ and $c\mid a'-b'$ then $c\mid aa'-bb'$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Show that if $c\mid a-b$ and $c\mid a'-b'$ then $c\mid aa'-bb'$:
I have tried to express $aa'-bb'$ in terms of $a-b$ and $a'-b'$ as:
$2(aa'-bb') = (a-b)(a'+b')+(a'-b')(a+b)$ which implies that $(aa-bb') = (a-b)(a'+b')/2+(a'-b')(a+b)/2$. However, there is no guarantee that all these terms are divisible by 2; how can I proceed?

Answer (score 5):

If $c\mid a-b$ and $c\mid a'-b'$, then $$c\mid (a-b)a'+(a'-b')b=aa'-bb'$$

---

Another proof: let $a-b=ck$ and $a'-b'=ct$ for some $k,t\in\mathbb Z$.

$$aa'-bb'=(b+ck)a'-b(a'-ct)=c(ka'+bt)$$

Another proof: $$aa'=(b+ck)(b'+ct)=bb'+c(bt+kb'+ckt)$$

Comment: Only three proofs?